# iOS App that controls the screen also when backgrounded

Tags: ios

Is there any way to implement an iOS app that has access to the screen (e.g. screen recording) also when it's backgrounded? Has anyone experience with this?

Apps like TeamViewer do this, but it's not clear to me if they went through a special process with Apple (e.g. a non-open API).

P.S. I am of course assuming that the user would have to explicitly accept this (e.g. like for system extensions on macOS), the goal here is not to make a malicious app but a remote-control tool.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to record the screen in the background is by using the broadcast upload extension in ReplayKit 2. This WWDC talk goes into more detail around how to use this API https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/601/

Since it's not specifically designed for your use case you will have to do some things differently like locally storing the frames in your App Group instead of uploading them.